# UserName Generator Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
from random import randint 
for i in range(5): 
    FN = (input("What is your name?"))
    firstletter = FN[:1] 
    SN = []
    first3letters = SN[:3]
    x = str(len(SN))
    sentence = str(randint(0,9))+(first3letters.lower())+(firstletter.upper()+(x))
    print(sentence)
```

I have been working on it, and I need to make the 5 usernames generated into an array - but I'm confused as to how I could do it, would anyone be able to help?

Comment: where is your code for looping?

Comment: Pls update your question with the code that you actually use. Otherwise it is misleading.

Comment: @gdlmx have updated the code!

Comment: @gdlmx did u get a chance to view it?

Comment: Seems that what you need is a python 101 tutorial. Is this some kind of homework question?

Comment: Sort of - just need a head start to finish this task completely (the end array is the last part)! @gdlmx

Comment: First, define an empty list `AllNames=[]` before the forloop. Second, at the end of the loop, replace the `print (sentence)` line with `AllNames.append(sentence)`. Last but not least, find a python book and spend some time on it.

Comment: Didn't work but thanks for ur help :) and will do @gdlmx

Answer (score 2):

try changing x = len(SN) to `x = str(len(SN))`

for the loop you need to indent the code within the loop. accepted syntax is four spaces so:

```
from random import randint

sentences = []
for i in range(5):
    FN = (input("What is your name?"))
    firstletter = FN[:1]
    SN = []
    SN = (input("What is your last name?"))
    first3letters = SN[:3]
    x = str(len(SN))

    sentence = str(randint(0,9))+(first3letters.lower())+(firstletter.upper()+x)
    print(sentence)
    sentences.append(sentence)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Would you know how to loop it 5 times? Also, why did u add str ? is there a specific reason? Please explain if possible

Comment: @PennyHarvard  because you can't concatenate strings and integers in python. Your `x` will be an integer and therefore you have to cast it to a string, that's what str() does. You are calling `str()` on your sentence but the inner brackets will get executed first, that's why you'll get an error.

Comment: @PennyHarvard I guess you'll have to ask more specifically what you don't understand and open another thread. These links should help you understand your code a little bit better though: https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html and http://www.pitt.edu/~naraehan/python2/data_types_conversion.html

Comment: @PennyHarvard this is called list slicing and it's explained in my first link. You should really check them out.

Comment: @Grr Sorry to keep bothering, last question! For the 5 usernames then generated, i need to let it print an array with all of them in it - help? thank you so so so much

Comment: @PennyHarvard See edited answer. That will give you a list named sentences with all of the usernames in them.

Comment: @Grr Hi! It doesn't work - instead it stops the username from showing overtime it is entered - and in the end only displays the 5th one?

Comment: @PennyHarvard So im not quite sure what you meant by that. I went back and tested the answer and I got a username printed after each first/last input request. If you want to see a list of all five you could call `print(sentences)` or call individual names with `print(sentences[x])` where x is the index of the username you want.